# Select Only the Fractional Part of a Number's value

Tags: mysql, numbers, decimal

How do I select only the part of the value of a number to the right of the decimal point?

So for example:

```
SELECT ____(10.1234) AS mynumber;
```

Where the result would be:

```
.1234 (or 1234)
```

Answer (score 34):

The [MOD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) should work:

```
SELECT MOD(10.1234, 1);
-- -> 0.1234
```

Comment: I prefer this solution since it evaluates the expression only once (which is very useful in many cases, for example if you call a `RAND()` or a heavy and/or a mutating function)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use below...

```
select substring_index(field1,'.',1), substring_index(field1,'.',-1) from table1;
```

Sample output

```
mysql> select substring_index(120.45,'.',1), substring_index(120.45,'.',-1) ;
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| substring_index(120.45,'.',1) | substring_index(120.45,'.',-1) |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 120                           | 45                             |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: used substring_index string function to extract integral part and decimal part..  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: If your number hasn't a "." (an entire number), that doesn't function correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Simply subtract the integer part:

```
select mynumber - truncate(mynumber,0) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use floor() function

```
select mynumber - floor(mynumber) from mytable
```